# Chromecast APIs in Android WebViewClient

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient, chromecast

My Android app has a WebViewClient for the UI. It is launched within an instance of a WebView.
Will my WebViewClient be able to access Chromecast Sender APIs to discover and communicate with any receivers?
As far as I understand, I can use Chromecast APIs only in my native Android code. Another alternative is to package up my app as a Chrome App.

Answer (score 2):

WebViewClient cannot be used as a Chrome sender directly since for a chrome sender to work, it has to have the Chromecast extension installed to provide the needed API to communicate  to the receiver (discovery and the rest).

Comment: Yes, you are right. As per my understanding, this extension is injected by Chrome while loading web pages that are whitelisted for Chrome Sender APIs. Since my WebView is not really a Chrome instance, how can I get these extensions to be installed/loaded for my WebViewClient to use?

Comment: You can't add/install any extension.